# How to distribute JSON Schema to users?

Tags: json, yaml, jsonschema

I am working on a Python application that gets a YAML file from users as input. The YAML file is pretty complex; therefore, I have a JSON Schema for it. However, I don't know how to distribute this JSON Schema to potential users of my application.

Should I create extensions for popular IDEs? Or should I give step-by-step tutorials on how to set up the JSON schema in their IDEs? I would like to find the most user-friendly way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide it a multitude of ways.

- serve it statically from an endpoint
  e.g.
  `www.example.com/schema`  using the header `content-type: application/schema+json`
- You can host it in a git repo
- You can host it on your own site
- You can add it to [www.schemastore.org](http://www.schemastore.org)
- You can bundle it with your package

Comment: But then, I must provide them with a tutorial on setting up this schema, right? I expect my users not even to know what a JSON schema is, but I would like them to edit their input files with the schema comfort.

Comment: If they can maneuver a complex yaml input file, It should be expected they can follow a schema. If you want to provide additional documentation, that's up to you. You would need to know which IDE your users are using

Comment: I don't agree with this. Even I didn't know what a JSON Schema was until I decided to publish this application. But I have used lots of applications that required YAML inputs (mkdocs, quarto, etc.), and I have never manually set up a JSON schema. However, I was using it without knowing it (they did something). There should be an elegant way other than saying: "Go to settings, type JSON Schema, select the file I provided to you,..."

Comment: Any of those other companies or projects did the same that I recommended to you. They hosted their schema and then provide documentation on how to set it up so when they used an IDE the auto completion helps them understand it

Comment: Most IDEs and editors integrate with schemastore.org including vscode and jetbrains that I know of. So, that should cover distribution. Vscode (and I think most others) allow users to put `$schema: uri_of_your_schema` at the top of their yaml file and it will automatically validate. That's likely all you need to document. You can provide guides for other IDEs or editors that don't support that syntax, but I'd just document that users need to associate the schema with their yaml and let them figure it out for their chosen environment.